# Strictly increasing and strictly decreasing derivatives

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, proof-writing

How do I prove this? We don't have that strictly increasing implies $f' > 0$, but we do have the converse; and, things like Rolle's Theorem and statements of the mean value theorem, and that $f'$ exists implies that $f$ is continuous:

> Suppose $f'$ exists on $(a, b)$ and $f'(x) \neq 0$ on $(a, b)$. Prove
>   that either $f'(x) > 0$ for all $x \in (a, b)$ or $f'(x) < 0$.

My attempts don't seem rigorous.

Comment: I have tried to make edits to the question to clean it up. However, there must be at least a couple typos still lurking or some missing information. For example, take $a = -1$, $b = 1$ and $f(x) = x$.

Comment: The statement is false as written. Take $(a,b) = (0,2)$, $f(x) = x-1$. Then $f'(x) = 1$ for all $x$ on $(0,2)$, so it is never zero, but $f(0.5) = -0.5\lt 0$ and $f(1.5) = .5\gt 0$. Is the conclusion supposed to be that the **derivative** (not the function) is always positive or always negative?

Comment: @cardinal: Possibly the conclusion is supposed to be that either $f\;'(x)>0$ for all $x\in(a,b)$ or $f\;'(x)<0$ for all $x\in(a,b)$, in which case it’s essentially [Darboux’s theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_%28analysis%29).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Yes, that was my thought, too. But, I wanted to leave it to the OP to think about and sort out. :)

Comment: Sorry, @BrianM.Scott is correct.

Comment: @totok: Please don't erase the question! It kills all the context.

Comment: I didn't mean to! I meant to erase the things irrelevant to the problem at this point (leaving the gray box). Would that be frowned upon?

Comment: @totok: Simply posting a question as if you were assigning homework is considered rude by many readers (myself included); putting context is much better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming the conclusion is supposed to be that $f'(x)$ is either always positive or always negative (rather than $f(x)$), since the conclusion is false for $f(x)$ (If it were true for a function $f$, then doing a suitable vertical translation you would be able to get a function which is sometimes positive and sometimes negative on $(a,b)$, without changing the derivative.

Assume there are points $d,e$ with$ a\lt d\lt e\lt b$ and $f'(d)\lt 0 \lt f'(e)$.

By the Extreme Value Theorem, $f(x)$ achieves a maximum and a minimum on $[d,e]$, and this minimum is achieved at a critical point or at an endpoint. By hypothesis, there are no critical points, so the minimum must be achieved at $d$ or at $e$.

Show that the fact that $f'(d)\lt 0$ implies that $f$ cannot achieve its minimum over $[d,e]$ at $d$. One can do this by using the definition of derivative as a limit.

*Added.* Here is how one can prove this without trying to show that $f$ is decreasing on a neighborhood of $d$: by definition,
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(d+h)-f(d)}{h} = f'(d)\lt 0.$$
In particular,
$$\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{f(d+h)-f(d)}{h} = f'(d)\lt 0.$$
By definition of the limit, for every $\epsilon\gt 0$ there exists $\delta\gt 0$ such that if $0\lt h\lt \delta$, then $\left|\frac{f(d+h)-f(d)}{h} - f'(d)\right|\lt \epsilon$. Take $\epsilon= |f'(d)/2$, and let $\delta_0$ be the corresponding $\delta$. Then for any $h$, $0\lt h\lt \delta_0$ we have
$$\left|\frac{f(d+h)-f(d)}{h} - f'(d)\right| \lt \frac{|f'(d)|}{2}.$$
From this, we conclude that $\frac{f(d+h)-f(d)}{h}\lt 0$. Since $h\gt 0$, that means that $f(d+h)-f(d)\lt 0$, or $f(d+h)\lt f(d)$. This holds for all $h$ with $0\lt h\lt \delta_00$. That means that $f(d)$ is strictly larger than all values of $f$ on $(d,d+\delta_0)$, so $f(d)$ cannot be the minimum on $[d,d+\delta_0)$, and so cannot be the minimum on $[d,e]$.

Likewise, show that the fact that $f'(e)\gt 0$ implies that $f$ cannot achieve its minimum over $[d,e]$ at $e$. This contradiction arises from the assumption that we can find points $d$ and $e$ with $f'(d)\lt 0 \lt f'(e)$. Replace $f$ with $-f$ to show you cannot find points $d$ and $e$ with $f'(d)\gt 0 \gt f'(e)$ either.

Comment: Doesn't this require that the derivative be continuous?

Comment: @totok: Let me ask you this: Did you *try* to prove it along the lines I suggested, and found that you needed continuity somewhere, or are you just wondering? If the latter, then I suggest you try the former. If the former, then *where* do you believe continuity is being assumed?

Comment: I tried to prove it. When you  say that $f'(d) < 0$ implies $f$ cannot have a minimum at $d$. There is an assumption that the $f'(d)$ is defined on the neighborhood around $d$, not just at $d$

Comment: @totok: I explicitly said that you should try to *prove it*, and I suggested that you do it by using the definition of the derivative as a limit. I do not assume continuity of the derivative, just that the derivative exists at $d$ and is negative. Think about what that means: it means that$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(d+h)-f(d)}{h}$$exists and is negative. Now restrict yourself to the right-handed limit, so $h\gt 0$. What does that tell you about all values of $f$ at points sufficiently close to $d$?

Comment: @totok: "Defined on a neighborhood of $d$" does not imply continuity. And we don't need to *assume* it's defined on a neighborhood of $d$. **We are told** that $f$ is differentiable on all $(a,b)$. So it is *certainly* defined on a neighborhood of $d$: namely, $(a,b)$. *But you don't need that* to conclude that $f(d)$ cannot be a minimum: just the derivative being negative at that point is more than enough.

Answer (score 2):

As ever, Arturo's response is right on the money.  But since there seem to be some doubts / lack of approval for Arturo's answer, let me offer a second (totally corroborating) opinion.

The theorem in question is called [Darboux's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_%28analysis%29), or sometimes "The Intermediate Value Theorem for Derivatives".  It states that for any differentiable function $f$, $f'$ has the intermediate value property, even though it need not be continuous.  This result, although simple to prove, is rather surprising.

As it happens, I proved this result in my "Spivak calculus" class last week, so the statement and proof can be found on page 20 of [these notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/2400calc2.pdf).  The proof uses the Extreme Value Theorem, and in fact *it differs in no essential way from the argument Arturo gives in his answer*.  This is a standard thing...

Answer (score -2):

Use  intermediate value property  for  derivative. If $f'$ is negative at  one point  and  positive  at  another,  then at  some  point  in between $f'$ will  take  the  value $0$ which  contradicts  the  hypothesis.

Comment: Don't use capital letters, PLEASE!